# How to find and replace multiple strings in multiple html files?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'd like to create a list of words that need to be replaced across multiple HTML files. How can I do that?

eg. replace:

- `cat` with `dog`
- `parrot` with `monkey`
- `fish` with `tiger`

across all HTML files in the selected catalog.

Comment: @muru Not really, as I want to create a list of strings to be replaced, not just one. I have too much text to do it one by one.

Comment: Who said sed can only replace one word at a time?

Answer (score 5):

You can place multiple `sed` expressions into a file, and apply them using the `-f` option:

```
-f script-file, --file=script-file

       add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed
```

Ex. given

```
$ cat > file
The cat sat on the mat.
The parrot chewed on a carrot.
The fish was just a fish.
```

then

```
$ cat > sedfile
s/cat/dog/g
s/parrot/monkey/g
s/fish/tiger/g

$ sed -f sedfile file
The dog sat on the mat.
The monkey chewed on a carrot.
The tiger was just a tiger.
```